# Why are there two screens when I only want one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Basically I made an application in turtle and I want to place the contents of the turtle app onto a Tkinter canvas. However, when I run the code, two screens are created when I only want one.

Here is example code:

```
from tkinter import *
import turtle                   
import time                     


 
# Screen
screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(screen.winfo_screenwidth(), screen.winfo_screenheight())) 
screen.title("Example Code")
screen.configure(bg="Gray")
# Canvas
canvas = Canvas(screen, width="666", height="666")
canvas.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)




# Making The User
user = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
user.shape("triangle")
user.setheading(90)
user.speed(0)
user.color("black")
user.down()
user.goto(0, 0)
userspeed = 15

 

 
 
# Moving Functions
def move_up():
    y = user.ycor()
    y += userspeed
    if y > 280:
        y = 280
    user.sety(y)
    user.setheading(90)  # Changes Direction of the Head
 
 
def move_down():
    y = user.ycor()
    y -= userspeed
    if y < -280:
        y = -280
    user.sety(y)
    user.setheading(-90)  # Changes Direction of the Head
 
 
def move_left():
    x = user.xcor()
    x -= userspeed
    if x < -280:
        x = - 280
    user.setx(x)
    user.setheading(60)  # Changes Direction of the Head
 
 
def move_right():
    x = user.xcor()
    x += userspeed
    if x > 280:
        x = 280
    user.setx(x)
    user.setheading(0)  # Changes Direction of the Head
 
 
# Keyboard Bindings For Moving Functions
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(move_up, "Up")
turtle.onkey(move_down, "Down")
turtle.onkey(move_left, "Left")
turtle.onkey(move_right, "Right")

screen.mainloop()
```

When I run this, two screens are created (a Tkinter screen and a turtle screen), I only want the Tkinter screen. However, when I close the turtle screen the keyboard bindings do not work on the Tkinter screen. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the event for turtle.Just add it in the `tkinter.canvas`.You could try this code below:

```
from tkinter import *
import turtle
import time

# Screen
screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(screen.winfo_screenwidth(), screen.winfo_screenheight()))
screen.title("Example Code")
screen.configure(bg="Gray")
# Canvas
canvas = Canvas(master=screen, width="666", height="666")
canvas.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

# Making The User
user = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
user.shape("triangle")
user.setheading(90)
user.speed(0)
user.color("black")
user.down()
user.goto(0, 0)
userspeed = 15


# Moving Functions
def move_up(event=None):
    y = user.ycor()
    y += userspeed
    if y > 280:
        y = 280
    user.sety(y)
    user.setheading(90)  # Changes Direction of the Head


def move_down(event=None):
    y = user.ycor()
    y -= userspeed
    if y < -280:
        y = -280
    user.sety(y)
    user.setheading(-90)  # Changes Direction of the Head


def move_left(event=None):
    x = user.xcor()
    x -= userspeed
    if x < -280:
        x = - 280
    user.setx(x)
    user.setheading(60)  # Changes Direction of the Head


def move_right(event=None):
    x = user.xcor()
    x += userspeed
    if x > 280:
        x = 280
    user.setx(x)
    user.setheading(0)  # Changes Direction of the Head


# Keyboard Bindings For Moving Functions
# turtle.listen()
# turtle.onkey(move_up, "Up")
# turtle.onkey(move_down, "Down")
# turtle.onkey(move_left, "Left")
# turtle.onkey(move_right, "Right")
canvas.focus_set()
canvas.bind("<Up>", move_up)
canvas.bind("<Down>", move_down)
canvas.bind("<Left>", move_left)
canvas.bind("<Right>", move_right)
screen.mainloop()
```